# sqlcmd scripting variables understanding problem

Tags: sql-server, variables, sqlcmd

try to run sqlcmd from powershell with some variables.
But get error.

Simple test. I know that this select is really simple but it is sufficient to show the problem.

this is the content of my sql file:

```
USE [master]
select name from sys.databases  where NAME = $(db)
GO
```

now i run this:
`sqlcmd -S testserver -v db="Test" -i \mssql_duplicate\testvariable.sql`

i get following message:

Meldung "207", Ebene "16", Status "1", Server "testserver", Zeile 2
"Ungültiger Spaltenname **"Test"."**

So my question: Why the sqlcmd do this conversion?
When i put he name in the sql script it runs fine:

```
USE [master]
select name from sys.databases  where NAME = "TEST"
GO

sqlcmd -S testserver -i \mssql_duplicate\testvariable.sql
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLCMD variables can substitute anything, in particular databases' and objects' names. In your example, however, it is used as an ordinary parameter, which is supposed to be of `nvarchar(128)` data type. So your code should look like this:

```
USE [master];
select name from sys.databases  where NAME = N'$(db)';
GO
```

Without single quotes, SQL Server interprets your variable as an object name, hence the error.

Comment: LOL... thank you so much. I tried different syntax but this is finally right.

Comment: @MarcelS, also, the literal should be `N'$(db)'` to denote a Unicode literal in this case, not that it will matter if you use only ANSI characters.